# Как подключить arduino к Matlab

Tags: arduino, matlab

Поставил матлаб 2016
Добавил пакеты для работы матлаба и симулинк с ардуино.
Какой сketch надо залить в ардуино, чтобы управлять ей из матлаба?

Comment: Вы уже что то пробовали сами почитать на офф сайте? https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/arduino-and-matlab-reading-inputs-and-writing-outputs-106502.html

Answer (score 0):

С помощью пакета ArduinoIO.
[Подключаем Arduino к MATLAB](http://robocraft.ru/blog/741.html)

Comment: arduino.Prefs.setArduinoPath('c:\ArduinoTarget')

Comment: Пишет что метода Prefs не существует